# POST request 500 error on android device - local server

Tags: php, android, laravel, post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to write a mobile application with my own server. Server, which I wrote is on PHP with Laravel framework and hosted by xampp on local machine. I manage to connect via my phone - browser to open that my local site. But I want to write a mobile application and get to the server via HttpUrlConnection.

With my browser everything works fine. But my POST request gives me 500 - code. I guess that the problem is with the request properties but I do not know what to write.

My android - post - request code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    URL url = null;
   try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("name", bundle.getString("name"));
                jsonObject.put("password", bundle.getString("password"));
                jsonObject.put("email", bundle.getString("email"));


                url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101:8081/UserAdd");

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
try {
        byte[] bytes = jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
       // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "localhost:8081");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        if (flag) {
            urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        }

        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        /*BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();*/
        os.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        urlConnection.connect();


        boolean redirect = false;

        int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                redirect = true;
        }

        if (redirect) {
            String newUrl = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
            String cookies = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

        }

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        resultJson = buffer.toString();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My network request header from computer browser. I think I need this cookie fields but I do not know where to find it, because that laravel - issue. I am very new to it. I am asking your help, guys.

[image]

Comment: Just a guess. The PHP file you are calling has some syntax error.

Comment: But that file and route IS working via computer and mobile browsers. Or is there something I misunderstood in your guess? @Nandan

Comment: http://192.168.1.101:8081/UserAdd is the local IP of your xamp server ?

Comment: What do you mean by `mobile application and get to the server via HttpUrlConnection` ? Are you talking about the live server, or the localhost where your files are hosted ?

Comment: I suggest using libraries like Retrofit, Volley or OkHttp for networking. They make your life much easier when consuming JSON via REST calls. They are faster(http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/) and provide support for JSON converters like GSON, etc.

Comment: @Nandan, well. My files are hosted by local server on my pc. And this is "192.168.1.101:8081/UserAdd" - the address to it, yes.

Comment: Just do a quick check. Delete all the codes in the file and just echo "Somevalue" in your PHP file. Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, because I have no Idea about your back-end script but do make sure the following things.

1. You are using **POST** in the for the route. I doubt that you are using **GET** since you are able to load the page using the browser. Example,

   ```
   Route::post('UserAdd', 'Controller@UserAdd');
   ```
2. Once again verify that you don't have any errors in the controller/the PHP file.
3. If you are using any authController, check whether you have valid permission.
4. Check .htaccess file.